# Sprite Kit. Follow Node Position (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Is there a way for a sprite node to follow another sprite node with an SKAction? i am using this but it doesn't seem to fully catch up with my rocket.

```
move = [SKAction moveTo:_rocket.position duration:1.0];
[beams runAction:move];
```

I have a rocket firing a laser beam at another rocket, and i want the beam to follow the rocket when it fires, but also slowly catch up to it so it hits it. The code above does follow it but stays slightly behind it.

Here is the code for my two movements for the rockets

```
SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveByX: 100.0 y:0 duration:2];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveRight]];
SKAction *endless = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
[spaceShip runAction:endless withKey:@"rocketKey"];


Second Rocket 
SKAction *moveShip = [SKAction moveByX:150.0f y:0 duration:2.00f];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveShip]];
SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];

[spaceShipL runAction:repeat];
```

I've tested it without the SKAction and it would work fine but i need both of the rockets to be always moving.

Comment: are you trying to make a homing effect?  If you are trying to have the beam reach the rocket, it will never happen.  Your code is saying take 1 second to move to the rockets position,  so as the beam gets closer to the rocket, it will move slower because the gap is smaller, but if the rocket does not stay still, the beam can never reach it.  instead of moveTo, you need  to do some kind of alternative.  The best would be to use `velocity` and calculate velocity using trigonometry (sin's and cos's) based on where the beam is, to where the beam should be going

Comment: ah, ok. didn't think you could do it this way as i've been trying for ages. just found a tutorial using trig with sprite kit so i'll have a good look at that.

Comment: sprite kit allows for custom actions as well,  so what you could do is use that.  How you use it is when the custom action is called,  a duration of how long has passed is dropped into it.  You take this duration, and multiply it by the velocity to get the velocity for that particular duration (If your rocket travels at 60 miles per hour and 1 minute has passed, your change in velocity would be 1 mile)  Then do your math inside this action that changes the angle of your beam to have its nose point to the enemy, and apply the thrust.

Comment: Apple docs has a nice example of how to the thrust part.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to achieve this that I know of.

1. You *could* use some kind of [pathfinding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html).
2. You could add your laser beam as a child to rocket2, and move it relative to that rocket. (You would need some extra calculations to ensure that if rocket2 should move towards the laser, the laser won't slow down/move backwards)
3. Best solution, regularly get the position of rocket2 and have the laser follow it. Rather than using moveTo, use applyForce. This won't be bound by time, and so should be able to catch up to your rocket:

   ```
   SKSpriteNode *laser = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"laser"];
   laser.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture: laser.texture size: laser.texture.size];

   static const CGFloat thrust = 0.10;
   CGVector thrustVector = CGVectorMake(thrust*cosf(laserDirection),
                              thrust*sinf(laserDirection));
   [laser.physicsBody applyForce:thrustVector];
   ```